# Issue regarding to make a checkbox having a particular value set using Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I want to set a checkbox having a particular value checked using jquery. Now I am using the following line of code to achieve the goal.

Here it is:

```
$("input[id=brand_id_][value=" + only_brand_name + "]").prop('checked', true);
```

Where 'brand_id_' is the checkbox id and 'only_brand_name' is a string comes from other part of code.

Now this approach is working fine where the checkbox value is just a simple string without any white spaces and special characters. For example if the checkbox html is as:

```
<input class="brand_tag" id="brand_id_" name="brand_id[]" type="checkbox" value="ACC">
```

And the 'only_brnad_name' is 'ACC', then I can set the checkbox checked without having any issue by the given line of jquery code.

But if the checkbox html is as:

```
<input class="brand_tag" id="brand_id_" name="brand_id[]" type="checkbox" value="(Reputed)China Make">
```

And if 'only_brand_name' variable is exactly '(Reputed)China Make', then I am unable to set the checkbox 'checked' by the same line of jquery code. It seems a weird type of issue and got stuck here for a long time.

Please help me to figure out this. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: The brackets in the value may be causing a problem with the change in value try this. not sure if it will work, just a guess
value ="&#40; Reputed &#41; China Make"

Comment: Not only the brackets, white spaces are also causing problem.

Comment: maybe try a line before that strips out white-spaces  `$.trim(" test case ");` then `.replace(/\s+/g, '');`

Comment: `id="brand_id_"` - is that the literal value for the id, and are you using that on multiple elements? That would be invalid HTML.

Comment: You need quotes around the attribute selector value.

Comment: Thank you @CBroe...Your approach is working for me. Thanks a lot!